# Sinch managed push. Message contents

Tags: ios, sinch

I'm using Sinch for instant messaging in iOS application. I properly receive push notifications that indicates sender of the message. How can I also add part of message body to notifications?

Answer (score 0):

With managed push you can, if you want to add that you need to roll your own push solution that the sdk supports as well. https://www.sinch.com/docs/instant-message/android/#pushnotifications